# How to pass json file as an argument using docker run command

Tags: python, file, docker

Below is my Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install numpy==1.12.0

CMD ["python", "t_1.py", "t_1.json"]
```

I want to pass this file(t_1.sjon) as argument with docker run command at runtime so that CMD ["python", "t_1.py", "RUN TIME ARGUMENT"]. I tried mounting volumes but fails as json file is independent and I want as argument.

Please help.

Comment: Is "t_1.json" going to be stored inside the Docker image or you want to pass the file itself (and not only the file name) as run time argument?

Comment: @user3758302: I want to pass json file(file contents may vary each time) itself as runtime argument though filename is same, but cmd should be python t_1.py t_1.json

Comment: The key is mounting a volume or a "file" volume (i.e. docker run -v ./t_1.json:/data/t_1.json <dockerimage> as stated in Tarun Lalwani's answer). If eveything stays the same and only file contents change, an entrypoint won't harm but is not mandatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should use is `ENTRYPOINT`

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install numpy==1.12.0

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "t_1.py"]
```

Now when you run the docker command

```
docker run -v ./t_1.json:/data/t_1.json <dockerimage> /data/t_1.json
```

This will make it equivalent to `python t_1.py /data/t_1.json`

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash to run any command inside docker container.

```
docker run <your_image> bash -c "python /app/t_1.json"
```

I am assuming that the json file is in the directory where you are having the dockerfile. So it being copied inside the container at `/app`, can be run using the bash command inside container.