# Accessing `docker run` arguments from the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, uwsgi

I run an image like that:

```
docker run <image_name> <config_file>
```

where `config_file` is the path to a JSON file which contains the configuration of my application.

Inside the Dockerfile, I do

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", \
            "--log-encoder", "json {\"msg\":\"${msg}\"}\n", \
            "--http", ":80", \
            "--master", \
            "--wsgi-file", "app.py", \
            "--callable", "app", \
            "--threads", "10", \
            "--pyargv"]
```

At the same time, I would like to access some of the values in the configuration file in the Dockerfile. For example to configure the JSON log encoder of uWSGI.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass json file as an argument using docker run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611955/how-to-pass-json-file-as-an-argument-using-docker-run-command)

Comment: Note that you intrinsically can't access things passed in at `docker run` time in the Dockerfile: the `docker build` command runs to completion before any of those arguments or files are available.

Comment: @David Maze, yes, you are totally right. I haven't thought about that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. See comment by @David Maze.